# Laravel Eloquent triple Relationship

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am stuck in situation where I need relation between 3 different tables. My tables are `companies`, `products` and `Roles`. Companies can assign multiple `Roles` to multiple `products`. The problem is `Companies` do not have any relationship with `products`. Products are added through admin.

Currently I have made a table `company_product_role` with structure `company_id`, `product_id` and `role_id`, the problem is how to make eloquent relation for insertion and retrieval. Either I am doing it correct or there is simple solution for it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I've done something like this before where the pivot table, in your case `company_product_role`, actually has a Model assigned, like `CompanyProductRole`. The table would need a primary key (`id`) column so you can query and insert/edit like other models, then you would setup 3 relations for each `_id` column. Might not be the best approach, but worked for my needs.

Comment: Thats what I am thinking too. I didn't find any better approach :/